# Element not visible when calling click method

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver, selenium3

I'm trying to open a `</li>` element with this code:

```
DropDownElementByText("language-dd", "Englisch");

public void DropDownElementByText(string elementId, string text)
    {
        using (var dr = new ChromeDriver {Url = "https://www.startpage.com/deu/advanced-search.html"})
        {
            dr.Manage().Window.Maximize();

            var wait = new WebDriverWait(dr, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            IWebElement languageDropDown = wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='" + elementId + "']/ul")));

            //new Actions(dr).MoveToElement(languageDropDown).Perform();

            ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> languages = languageDropDown.FindElements(By.TagName("li"));
            foreach (IWebElement li in languages)
            {
                IWebElement a = dr.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='" + elementId + "']/ul/li/a[text()='" + text + "']"));

                if (a != null)
                {
                    new Actions(dr).MoveToElement(li).Perform();
                    //li.Click();
                    li.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

But  `li.SendKeys(Keys.Enter)` or `li.Click()` both give me "Test method SeleniumTests.SeleniumTests.TestMethod1 threw exception: 
OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why were you creating `Iwebelement a` and why are you using `SendKeys`, if click works.

Here's the update code (which is working for me):

```
 var dropdown = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='language-dd']"));
var coll = Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='language-dd']/ul/li"));
foreach (var item in coll)
{
    dropdown.Click();
    item.WaitForElementToBeClickable(30);
    item.Click();
}

public static void WaitForElementToBeClickable(this IWebElement element, int timeout)
{
    new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(element));
}
```

Comment: Click on languageDropDown throws ElementNotVisibleException also. It isn't a select element. You can check for yourself at the provided URL since it's a public site.

Comment: IWebElement a should select a single language. The updated code works - thanks!

Comment: @Shabbazz If it works, Please [accept it as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).